# Problem updating object in state with values from four different select tags

Tags: reactjs, state

So I have a product design page where the user will select options from 4 different select fields and then from that the image of the product will show. So im going to update the picture based on an object in state with each parameter inside it, but Im having problems updating the state.

I originlly had one handlechange which updated all the values in the object, then tried multiple handlechange functions as below and tried spreading in each parameter value but that doesnt work either, here is the component as of now below. It currently updates the state but deletes the other items in the object once a dropdown is selected. I guess this is fixed by using prevstate somehow but not sure.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import placeholder from '../../imgs/CPC Yellow Cube Planter.jpg'



class Design extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state= 
    {
      value: { 
        plantstyle: "",
        size: "",
        colour: "",
        finish: ""
    }
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);
    this.handleChange3 = this.handleChange3.bind(this);
    this.handleChange4 = this.handleChange4.bind(this);

  }


  handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({
        value: {
                  plantstyle: event.target.value,
               }
      })
  }

  handleChange2(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: {
                size: event.target.value,
             }
    })
}

handleChange3(event) {
  this.setState({
    value: {
              colour: event.target.value,
           }
  })
}

handleChange4(event) {
  this.setState({
    value: {
              finish: event.target.value,
           }
  })
}



  sweetalertFunc() {
    Swal.fire(
      'Design a planter!',
      'Personalise you product with the dropdown menus below.',
      'info'
    )
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">

          <h1>
            Design A Planter
       </h1>


          <div className="destext">
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
          </div>

          <div className="start"><button className="astext" onClick={this.sweetalertFunc}>How does it work? </button></div>

        <form>
          <div className="select">
                <select name="plantstyledd" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}>
                        <option value="">Style</option>
                        <option value="Pillar">Pillar</option>
                        <option value="Vase">Vase</option>
                        <option value="Column">Column</option>
                        <option value="Cube">Cube</option>

                </select> 

                <select name="size" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange2(e)}>
                        <option size="">Size</option>
                        <option size="small">Small</option>
                        <option size="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option size="large">Large</option>
                </select> 

                <select name="Colour" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange3(e)}>
                    <option value="">Select colour</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                    <option value="brown">Brown</option>
                    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                </select>

                <select name="Paint Finish" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange4(e)}>
                        <option value="">Finish</option>
                        <option value="Wood">Matt</option>
                        <option value="Wood">Paint</option>
                </select> 

            </div>

            <div className="desimg">
              <img src={placeholder} alt="placeholder"></img>

            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Design
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd restructure it like this:

```
class Design extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: {
        plantstyle: "",
        size: "",
        colour: "",
        finish: "",
      },
    };
  }

  handleChange = field => event =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: {
        ...prevState.value,
        [field]: event.target.value,
      },
    }));

  sweetalertFunc() {
    Swal.fire("Design a planter!", "Personalise you product with the dropdown menus below.", "info");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <h1>Design A Planter</h1>

        <div className="destext">
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className="start">
          <button className="astext" onClick={this.sweetalertFunc}>
            How does it work?{" "}
          </button>
        </div>

        <form>
          <div className="select">
            <select name="plantstyle" value={this.state.value.plantstyle} onChange={this.handleChange("plantstyled")}>
              <option value="">Style</option>
              <option value="Pillar">Pillar</option>
              <option value="Vase">Vase</option>
              <option value="Column">Column</option>
              <option value="Cube">Cube</option>
            </select>

            <select name="size" value={this.state.value.size} onChange={this.handleChange("size")}>
              <option size="">Size</option>
              <option size="small">Small</option>
              <option size="medium">Medium</option>
              <option size="large">Large</option>
            </select>

            <select name="colour" value={this.state.value.colour} onChange={this.handleChange("colour")}>
              <option value="">Select colour</option>
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="brown">Brown</option>
              <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            </select>

            <select name="finish" value={this.state.value.finish} onChange={this.handleChange("finish")}>
              <option value="">Finish</option>
              <option value="Wood">Matt</option>
              <option value="Wood">Paint</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="desimg">
            <img src={placeholder} alt="placeholder" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Design;
```

Perhaps as the most basic refactor would introduce only the function "handleChange" because through curry you are passing the key of the object to modify its value, so you are not repeating the code 4 times keeping the rest of the object as it is.

I hope I helped you :)

Comment: You could just use the 'name' attribute instead of sending field attribute to set state.

Comment: Hi i replied to a comment above with the error I get in browser and yours gives the same error TypeError: event.target is null

Comment: @matthewg could you upload all the files to a sandbox project? Because with the code above it should work, thanks!

Comment: Edit: got it fixed had to have event.target.value in a variable before the setstate(), thank you for the help

Comment: @matthewg that's great, i'm glad! (you have to mark the check if we've helped you in both solutions to solve your problem) :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain previous values in state like this -

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
     value: {
        ...prevState.value,
        plantstyle: event.target.value,
     }
  }))
}
```

Comment: When I implement this when I load the page in browser I get the error "TypeError: event.target is null" in the setstate function, do you know why this is?